# Why are my monospace fonts behaving erratically?

Tags: fonts, kde-plasma-workspace

I'm setting up an Arch box and I've installed Plasma 5 as my desktop environment.  However, monospace fonts are behaving very erratically:

- Listed in the 'Fonts' prefpane, it displays fine.
- As part of a terminal emulator, it's fine.
- Firefox slants them something awful in some cases (see forum), and
- will completely miss them in other cases (see post).

It's probably worthwhile to note that evaluating `(set-default-font "Oxygen Mono")` in emacs fails with

> Invalid font name: `-unknown-Oxygen-Sans-normal-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1`,

suggesting to me that there is some font registration issue.  (Note that it's looking for Oxygen Sans…)

How can I achieve sanity and convince these fonts to behave?

[image: example]

#### Additional information from continuing research:

- `$ fc-match mono` gives `Oxygen-Sans.tff: "Oxygen Sans" "Sans-Book"`
- `$ fc-match foo`  *also* gives `Oxygen-Sans.tff: "Oxygen Sans" "Sans-Book"`

Comment: @Downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: Looks like leading zero `0` instead of letter `O` `0xygen Mono 9`?

Comment: `Oxygen vs 0xygen` – doesn't look like it.

Comment: I think the problem is that "Oxygen-Sans" has a hyphen in it.

Answer (score 0):

As [sid-kap](https://superuser.com/users/431423/sid-kap) [commented](https://superuser.com/questions/944635/why-are-my-monospace-fonts-behaving-erratically#comment1657259_944635), the dash in the font name is breaking Emacs. He describes [a way to fix this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29397/8706) involving [fonttools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools).