# fc-match gives the same font regardless of query

Tags: fonts, fontconfig

Related: [Why are my monospace fonts behaving erratically?](https://superuser.com/q/944635/160871)

No matter what input I give `fc-match`, it always returns the same thing.  I think this is the root cause of the related Q above.

[image: output]

How would I go about debugging this issue?

---

Following-up on the comment section, the output of `FC_DEBUG=4 fc-match mono` is available in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Jkn94Vf0). Far more output than SE allows.

Comment: Your font-config configuration files are messed up. Try completely removing and reinstalling it.

Comment: @Larssend Hmm, any idea on how to completely remove it? `pacman` won't let me uninstall it since it's required by other packages (and there doesn't seem to be an option to force the matter). I tried forcing an install (which conveniently updated the font cache), but I don't think it removed any of the existing files.

Comment: I did find http://englanders.us/~jason/howtos.php?howto=fontconfig (scroll to the bottom) and am going to be trying the 'hands-on' approach, as it were. Unless there's a better option, of course :)

Comment: @Larssend No luck with the manual remove / reinstall approach :(

Comment: Re-installed all packages with [`pacman -Qns | pacman -S -`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#How_do_I_reinstall_all_packages.2C_retaining_information_on_whether_something_was_explicitly_installed_or_as_a_dependency.3F) and rebooted – still no luck.

Comment: @Larssend Perhaps my self-answer gives you an even better clue as to what might be going wrong? (Thanks for the conf-file lead, by the way.)

Comment: You could try looking through the debug output of eg `FC_DEBUG=4 fc-match sans`. see `man fonts.conf` for debug values.

Comment: @meuh I'll take a look at that manpage, thanks! I've added a link to the output of that debug information, but you can probably imagine it will take a while for me to sort through. Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution so much as a hack-around.

From [How to set default fonts and font aliases on Linux](http://seasonofcode.com/posts/how-to-set-default-fonts-and-font-aliases-on-linux.html), I added the following within the `<fontconfig>` node of `~/config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`:

```xml
<alias>
  <family>monospace</family>
  <prefer><family>Source Code Pro</family></prefer>
  <!-- Obviously, customize your preference above -->
</alias>
```

I'm still very much interested in a *real* solution for this.